# How do I know if the decryption is using multiple CPU as theory says?

Tags: encryption, openssl

Websites and books are saying the AES-CBC is a single-thread decryption process and CTR/CCM/GCM/Chacha20Poly1305 has the ability to do encryption and decryption in parallel.

To compare how much performance such a parallel algorithm can be brought, I have tried many methods and attempted to observe the performance difference between these algorithms.

- Python3 with pycryptodome, did not see an obvious difference on time
  cost, or CPU usage (only one of the CPUs was 100% and the others are
  idle).
- OpenSSL enc -aes-128-cbc and -aes-128-ctr does not seem has
  difference. Same as python, one CPU core is fully loaded and the rest
  are idle.

I also wanted to give it a try on GCM and CCM mode but I have not found an easy way to perform file encryption on my Linux machine.

Could anyone help to enlighten me if I understood the parallel concept incorrectly, or the methods I tried were not able to encrypt/decrypt in parallel, thanks in advance.

Comment: `has the ability to do encryption and decryption in parallel` while it may be so, you need to find an implementation that promises encryption in parallel. Further, to observe load on other cores you need to be encrypting something sufficiently large, e.g. take a 4GB file and feed it in because anything small might not even be enough to load it and many small files would effectively be running on the same thread anyway

Comment: @zaitsman thanks for your reply. yes, I used exactly a 4GB file during the tests. I think the difficulties are finding a correct method to utilize the cores and I have no clues what I can do next.

Comment: No, by default the generic implementations are using a serialised (single thread) approach. The parallel implementations are having it's own challenges, such as how to ensure valid integrity (gcm auth tag,..) or if the system is i/o bound, the parallel decryption has no advantage

Comment: Even if the cryptographic operations you mention can be performed in parallel they are usually not implemented that way. Crypto implementations prefer safety and security over performance. So the usual approach is to rely on fast hardware implementations (e.g. AES-NI CPU commands which can process several hundred MB per second) instead of parallelization.